# How to convert "Excel Xml"/"Xml Spreadsheet 2003", to .xlsx format without office/excel install

Tags: python, java, c#, excel

The input files are single XML files, that can be generated from excel using "Xml Spreadsheet 2003", often referred to as "Excel XML" format, and described in this namespace

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
```

(a simple file is at the end of this post for clarity).

I can potentially use dotnet, JVM or python, all of which have a enormous range of 3rd party libraries for excel manipulation but none (except excel) seem to be able to achieve this.

The only additional restriction is that excel cannot be a dependency, i.e. it will almost always not be present on the OS that runs the code.

Note: There are many many posts about very similar issues, but all come to dead end, mostly referring to 3rd party packages that don't support this format, or suggesting creating the input files in a different format (not an option).

example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author></Author>
  <LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
  <Created>2022-12-15T10:58:05Z</Created>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>5556</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>17256</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>32767</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>32767</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is an option someone I know gave me:

[groupdocs.conversion](https://products.groupdocs.com/conversion/net/xml-to-xlsx/#:%7E:text=Steps%20to%20convert%20XML%20to%20XLSX%20in%20C%23,full%20path%20and%20format%20%28XLSX%29%20as%20a%20parameter)

its a dotnet 3rd party library, not cheap but works for me in 3 lines of code (on the link)

tbh, this ticks the box for simplicity, though not cheap.